# Change CSS to increase font-size inside li

Tags: css, wordpress

I can't work out how to increase my font-size in the 'teaching points' section of this WP post http://www.test.foamped.com/2013/07/abdo-pain/

I'd like it to be 15px like the rest but it's only 12px.

I can't work out how to reference that section.  Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ul, ol 
{
  padding-left: 19px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Thanks
Ab

Comment: Welcome..luv Csses stuff..if you have any I will do it for you..

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to your `<ul>` element, ie: `teaching-points`, so you will have this UL structure:

```
<ul id="teaching-points">
```

Than in your CSS file declare it's properties:

```
ul#teaching-points li { font-size: 15px; }
```

And you're all done.

Comment: why set id if you dont use it?

teaching-points li{font-size: 15px;} should be better cuz of the scope

Comment: @JohanNordli - You are right. I was in a rush... corrected now :)

Comment: ok now its looking better :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the CSS style for font size like this

```
.entry-content ul li {
  font-size: 15px;     //newly added for li`s font size
   line-height: 1.7;
 }
```

for your reference this CSS is present at this location

http://www.test.foamped.com/wp-content/themes/liquidfolio/css/typography.css

**Note:This has been tested in Firefox v22.0**

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this style in your stylesheet.

```
.entry-content > ul > li {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this css

```
   .entry-content ul {
      font-size: 15px !important;
    }
```

**or**

```
.entry-content ul li {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

if it affects other "ul" then you need to add a class to the UL under teaching points. Like below:

```
 .entry-content ul.teachingPoint {
    font-size: 15px !important;
 }
```

Comment: !important is given because by default font size is taking 12px to replace 12px with 15px important used.

Comment: !important will override all the rules that are inheriting. I suggest it should be avoided to an extent where you are left with nothing but to use it not until trying the options available.

Comment: that's why I have mentioned if it override others(UL) then you need to add a class to particular UL.

Comment: In the class too you have declared `!important`.

Comment: you can add this you can't also..........it's depend on you.

Comment: `!important` is a bad solution. It should not be added just for the sake of things not working. Inheritance/Cascade matters.

Answer (score 0):

So as not to interfere with other aspects of the site, narrow the css to

```
div.entry-content > ul > li {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

You can place this in skin.css along with your other customizations